# Does AWS keep the same message id when it copies sqs message to dead-letter queues?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Sorry but I couldn't find this moment in the docs :(

When sqs decides to move message from queue to dead queue, does it keep original id or does it assign a new one to the message? Is there a guarantee that it always copies original id or it may copy or may not?

Comment: Did you try it to see whether it keeps the same ID? What was the result?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, AWS preserves the message id when moving a message to a dead-letter queue (DLQ).

> Amazon SQS moves the message to a dead-letter queue (with its original message ID)

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html

Answer (score 0):

Tried - message id is preserved. I think it's reasonable to assume that this is always the case.